# How do I hide the "Run | Debug" above main() text in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I normally run my application from the terminal directly so this text just adds a bit of noise. Any idea how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `rust-analyzer.lens.run.enable` and `rust-analyzer.lens.debug.enable` to `false` in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Note this will also disable lens on tests.